# How to extend database results in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find news from mongodb and then extend them with a key 'normal'

```
News.find().sort({date:-1}).exec(function(err, results) {
  if (err) return next(err);
    results.map(function(news) {
      news.normal = {
        title : news.title,
        description : news.description,
        content : news.content,
        image : news.image
      }
      return news
  })
  res.json(results);
```

but this gives me news without this key. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are not assigning the result of the map back to the results variable.

In other words - you were missing the 'results = ' part of 'results = results.map(fn(){})'

```
News.find().sort({date:-1}).exec(function(err, results) {
if (err) return next(err);
results = results.map(function(news) {
    news.normal = {
        title : news.title,
        description : news.description,
        content : news.content,
        image : news.image
    }
    return news
})
res.json(results);
```